# how can i perform single A-Z deployment of RDS , if subnet group must have 2 subnet of 2 different availability zone?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

Whenever I create RDS instance and while creating the DB subnet group, the system asks me to select 2 subnet of 2 different availability zones.
 Then how can I perform single A-Z deployment and what is then the use of multi a-z deployment??

Comment: Two availability zones is the least needed for your security, availability and infrastructure disaster recovery, consider reading this: https://aws.amazon.com/rds/details/multi-az/

Answer (score 6):

You can deploy an Amazon RDS database in a single Availability Zone. Simply do not select "Multi-AZ".

However, you *will* need to supply a database Subnet Group that contains two Availability Zones. The database will only use one of them.